# How to do a recursive funcion that uses a for

Tags: ocaml

Hello i want to implement a recursive function that uses a for and this for goes again to that function.
I have this code , can someone tell me whats wrong ?

```
 let rec mov m ini = 
 for i = 0 to nrf-1 do
 if m.(ini).(i) == 1 then mov m i 
 else
      m.(ini).(i)<- 0;
 done;;
```

basically i'm looking for something in the matrix that i want to implement in the matrix and search again.
But my sintax is wrong , can someone tell me why ?

Comment: There's no syntax error in this code according to my OCaml interpreter. I'm not sure it does anything sensible, but you said you had a syntax problem.

Comment: You failed to explain your problem in many points.  Your description of what you want with matrices is very unclear.  We have no enough information what error you got.  It is a syntax error, but you do not reoprt the location of the error.  Your code is not complete therefore we cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: I suspect the place you have to fix is before this function definition.  OCaml (and the other languages too) sometimes fails to report the exact point of syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

When running your code, utop gives me the following error:

```
Error: Unbound value nrf
```

This occurs because the toplevel does not know what `nrf` is (i.e. you have not declared it).

Now, I would imagine nrf was supposed to be the number of items in the matrix, so a possible fix would be to add it as a function argument, as below:

```
let rec mov m ini nrf= 
for i = 0 to nrf-1 do
if m.(ini).(i) == 1 then mov m i 
else
  m.(ini).(i)<- 0;
done;;
```

Then an example call would be `move m 0 20` where your matrix m that has been previously declared has 20 elements and search starts from 0.